# Go build not finding vendor packages ensured with dep

Tags: go, godeps

I'm running into an error where vendor packages are not being correctly resolved by go; on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I'll use github.com/gorilla/mux as an example package

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/gregorysims/go

$ go version
go version go1.11 darwin/amd64 

$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/gregorysims/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/gregorysims/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/tb/6c5vksm558q5q4t0fxfscgy80000gp/T/go-build409352678=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I'm importing the package with

```
import (
    ...
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    ...
)
```

When running:

```
go build -o out main.go
```

I get the following error for each package in vendor

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "_/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/_/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/_/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

The folder should be found at

```
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux
```

and is present in the directory.

Why is this being prefixed the following?

```
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/_
```

**UPDATE**

After deleting the local project and recloning from remote, I attempted to build without having any of the dependencies downloaded. This had the expected output:

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

The above error is produced only after the build command is run after `dep ensure` is run.

**UPDATE 2**

Creating an empty vendor directory changes the output to:

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
/Users/gregorysims/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
```

**Update 3**

To simulate dep I called `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` followed by:

```
mv $GOPATH/src/github.com/gorilla/mux $GOPATH/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux
```

After doing so, the problem surfaces again.

Comment: Can you try `go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Building after running that produces the exact same error

Comment: To note, I also attempted to build in a Docker container to try to rule out if it was my environment which was causing the problem. I get the same error (but with paths slightly changed) in a Docker container based on golang:latest

Comment: What is the output of `echo $GOPATH`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna see the original post

Comment: Are you able to run `go run main.go` without the import ?

Comment: please show `go env`. How did you setup golang ?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1311

Comment: @mh-cbon I've added the `go env` output to the main post. 1311 doesn't appear to address the issue as the project is already in the GOPATH.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna  `go run main.go` runs as expected if I comment code relevant to imports.

Comment: @mh-cbon I installed go through brew

Comment: @mh-cbon Although, installing from the pkg on golang.org and the command line in the dep readme gives the same result.

Comment: are you sure you have no import statement using the string "_/Users/gregorysims/go/src/site/user/project/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux" ? Because when i look to the error message it really looks likes you have this somewhere in the code.

Comment: @mh-cbon A search through all the files shows that it doesn't exist anywhere, all imports are: "github.com/gorilla/mux"

Comment: After deleting and recloning the repository, so there are no dependencies are downloaded anywhere. I can build with expected results, see the main post for full update

Comment: See Update 3 on how to reproduce without dep

Comment: This could be **off-topic**, have you considered using [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna this error also occurs with gvm, just with different paths